# Extract text from a Cell before specific characters

Tags: excel

I have column that consists of following data:

XYZAB XYZAC XYZAD XYZAE

XYZ may be any digit from 100 to 200,000

The column may contain only first value or in any combination with other value e.g

XYZAC

XYZAC XYZAE

XYZAB XYZAD XYZAE

I need to extract all adjacent digits to AB, AC, AD and AE and copy them to another column.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: What do you mean by `I need to extract all adjacent digits to AB, AC, AD and AE`? What exactly do you want to extract?

Comment: Can you share part of the actual spreadsheet, its a little difficult to understand what you are describing

Comment: Following is the link to sample file: http://www.4shared.com/file/_2F-VIOMba/Sample.html

Comment: Hi Michael, did you get the sample file?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:  Replace `??` with , then something like:

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)
```

copied down to suit, then select all, Copy, Paste Special, Values followed by select column and Text to Columns with Space as the delimiter. Sort the columns and move to suit.